# Undefined method `name' for "SystemTimer":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am having a problem getting an old Ruby on Rails 2 app that hasn't worked in a year to work.

I'm trying to run `rake test:functionals` in the root of my project directory, but am getting `undefined method 'name' for "SystemTimer":String`.

I've pasted everything that I believe relevant to the problem here:
http://pastebin.com/NgBvystZ

Also, when I run rake itself, I get
`Errors running test:units!`
Not sure how to debug that.

I have copied and pasted everything that I think would be useful to understanding this problem. Your time is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the [SystemTimer](http://systemtimer.rubyforge.org/) gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: Another sign: undefined method `name' for "bundler":String

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between versions of RubyGems greater than 1.3.7 and versions of Rails less than 2.3.12. There are a few ways to solve this.

1. **Use Bundler**

   Bundler is [easy to install](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails23.html), fixes this problem, and has a number of other advantages as well. I highly recommend it.
2. **Upgrade to Rails 2.3.12 or higher**

   Rails 2.3.12 fixed compatibility issues with RubyGems 1.8.5 (see [release report](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-2-3-12-has-been-released/)).
3. **Downgrade to RubyGems 1.3.7**

   I would not recommended this unless you have no other choice. Use this command: `gem update --system 1.3.7`. Also, version 1.7.2 has partial compatibility (it will run, but freezing gems will fail and there are likely other issues).

Comment: You're right. This was the solution. I had to find the right packages to use with ruby since the RoR developers are not fans of backwards compatibility in any sense of the word. I managed to find an old list of packages with the version numbers and that saved me.

Comment: Adding Bundler to a Rails 2 project is very easy and solves this problem. If you are not using rvm and have multiple sites on the same server do this: `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to get an isolated copy of your gems.

Comment: Tried a bunch of different solutions but your first suggestion worked perfectly for me using RVM. I used two commands: `gem install rubygems-update -v 1.7.2` and then `update_rubygems --version=1.7.2`

Answer (score 4):

I chanced upon this thread, because I got the following error when migrating some Radiant 0.9.1 installations to a new server:

```
undefined method `name' for "RedCloth":String
```

> (3) The compromising solution: I haven't tested this personally, but I hear that rails 2.3 with bundler is compatible with the latest rubygems. If you're interested in this solution,  see http://gembundler.com/rails23.html for getting bundler to work under rails 2.3.

For me solution 3 was the only option, since we had other apps needing the latest rubygems on the system.
Just install bundler and follow thes steps on this page:
http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

And put this in a file called "Gemfile" in the app root:

```
source :gemcutter
gem "radiant", "0.9.1"
gem "sanitize"
gem "fastercsv"
gem "rmagick"
gem "rack", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "rake", ">= 0.8.3"
gem "RedCloth", ">= 4.0.0"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 2.3.11"
gem "mysql"
```

This is just my example. Start with only the first 2 lines, run `bundle update` and reload the page to see what else you might be missing.

Thank you Ben!